# html render before css appling when use laravel and vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i am using laravel and vuejs to develop single page application in my index.blade.php i am invoke app element vuejs

this is my index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layout.header')

<div id="app" v-cloak v-on:shownav="shownavO()">
    <nav_bar v-if="hide"  :authType="authType"  ></nav_bar>
    <menuuu v-if="hide" :authType="authType" ></menuuu>
    <router-view class="v-cloak--hidden"></router-view>
</div>
@extends('layout.footer')
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

in my layout.header  it is a blade file i include css file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="loading" lang="{{$lang}}" data-textdirection="{{$lang=='ar'?'rtl':'ltr'}}" id="app">
<!-- BEGIN: Head-->

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="description" content="Vuexy admin is super flexible, powerful, clean &amp; modern responsive bootstrap 4 admin template with unlimited possibilities.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="admin template, Vuexy admin template, dashboard template, flat admin template, responsive admin template, web app">
    <meta name="author" content="PIXINVENT">
    <title>munasbaty</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->

    @if(!isset($lang)||$lang=='en')

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/tether-theme-arrows.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/tether.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/shepherd-theme-default.css">
    <!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/colors.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/components.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/themes/dark-layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/themes/semi-dark-layout.css">

    <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/pages/dashboard-analytics.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/pages/card-analytics.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/plugins/tour/tour.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/css/pages/card-analytics.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/app-assets/vendors/css/pickers/pickadate/pickadate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/')}}/assets/css/style.css">
    @endif

</head>
<!-- END: Head-->

<!-- BEGIN: Body-->
<body>
```

when update the page or when open the project the application It appears this way in the beginning
[image: this is my website appear]

Comment: Can you please post the code you showed in this question with [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of many images?

Comment: i do that my frend

Comment: I think you have to fetch app.js first, then other assets